# Extra strong sunglasses for sensitive eyes

Tags: sunglasses, uv-protection

I have a damaged pupil that stays partially dilated. And regular polarized sunglasses which I am wearing over the regular glasses aren't working better than my prescription sunglasses. I have a new prescription that includes an extra coating on the polarized lens to make them darker. I haven't received them yet.
I think I am looking for sunglasses that are **extremely dark**. What is available? I do not ski or mountain climb, just everyday stuff. Sunny days are no fun anymore because the sun light even on hazy days is hard on my eye.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP states that this is not related specifically to outdoor activities.

Comment: He just says he doesn't ski or mountain climb, not that he doesn't go into the great outdoors.

Comment: @BenediktBauer - Name one *indoor* activity where you need protection from the sun... If you asked me, I'd say the sun is more than likely always outside, and questions about protection from the sun are on-topic as outdoor activities.

Comment: @ShemSeger Just for the record: I made up my mind and retracted my close vote.

Comment: @benedikt - The retraction shall be noted in the record. ;)

Answer (score 7):

These are generally known as glacier glasses. They are rated as Category 4 on the CE scale and you aren't supposed to drive while wearing them.

Sunglasses in Category 4 only transmit 4-8% of available visible light.

[Hidalogos sunglass guide](http://www.hidalgos.com/selecting-sunglasses/)
has a very complete list of  the different factors in choosing sunglasses.

Category 4 come in a wider range of styles than in the past. Julbo in particular makes
several models that don't resemble the classic leather side flap models. 
I can recommend their [Zebra](http://www.julbousa.com/lenses/zebra/) photochromic lens, but that may not work for you.

Category 3 might work for you as well, most standard sunglasses are only Category 2. You need to buy "sport" sunglasses to get Category 3 level glasses.

You can get prescription versions of some versions of these sunglasses.

Answer (score 0):

It might be overkill, but welding shops sell (at least) up to #5 shades as lightweight plastic glasses. Kinda ugly and very green, but the way darker than sun glasses. And you can still see the ground in front of you on a sunny day.

Comment: Indeed an overkill I hope!